# Apollo MockedProvider testing issues (my rendered component keeps disappearing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, apollo-client, react-testing-library

Disclaimer; I'm a bit new to react-testing-library (been using an admittedly older version of Enzyme) and the Apollo Query/MockedProvider components (been using the client via a JS service object),  so this may be a stupid question...

I have a component that receives a list of countries for which I am trying to write tests. What I would like to do is something like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing';
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import wait from 'waait';
import Countries, { countryQuery } from './Countries';
import { isTerminating } from 'apollo-link/lib/linkUtils';

const mockCountryName = 'sample country';
const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: countryQuery,
      vairables: {},
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        countries: [{ name: mockCountryName }],
      },
    },
  },
];

describe('when working with the countries component', () => {
  describe('and the component is loading', () => {
    let component;

    beforeAll(async (done) => {
      await act(async () => {
        component = render(
          <MockedProvider mocks={[]}>
            <Countries />
          </MockedProvider>
        );
      });
      done();
    });

    it('should have a title', () => {
      expect(component.getByText('Countries Component')).not.toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('should have a loading status', () => {
      expect(component.getByText('Loading...')).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
  });
});
```

When this runs, the second test (about loading status) fails as it looks like the component is only a body tag at that point. I tried changing beforeAll to beforeEach, but that just produced a component that had an Error indicator. I put some console.log statements in my component, and this is what they are showing me:

```
console.log src/components/Countries.js:45
      Loading is: true
    console.log src/components/Countries.js:46
      Error is: undefined
    console.log src/components/Countries.js:45
      Loading is: false
    console.log src/components/Countries.js:46
      Error is: Error: Network error: No more mocked responses for the query: {
        countries {
          name
          phone
          __typename
        }
      }
      , variables: {}
```

I'm wondering if it does not like the empty array passed in as the mocks property for the MockedProvider. But every example I've seen does it that way, so...

As an experiment, I added a second set of test to the spec file to see if it was just a weird timing issue with the component that was causing the issue. Here's the second test:

```
describe('and the component has data', () => {
    let component;

    beforeAll(async (done) => {
      await act(async () => {
        component = render(
          <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            <Countries />
          </MockedProvider>
        );
        await wait(0);
      });
      done();
    });

    it('should have a title', () => {
      expect(component.getByText('Countries Component')).not.toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('should have a loading status', () => {
      expect(component.getByText(mockCountryName)).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
  });
```

This has the same problem; the first test works (if I reorder the test, the one that first always works) but the second one fails, and the component seems to be an empty body tag.

Is there a way to make this type of test structure work? I don't like the idea of having to put everything into a single test, let alone the setup code for the component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but I think I found a workaround.

First, the empty array/loading issue was not an issue; I traced everything back to testing-library resetting/re-rendering the component between tests.

Here's what I did:

```js
describe('and the component is loading', () => {
    let component, pageTitle, loadingMessage;

    beforeAll(async (done) => {
      await act(async () => {
        component = render(
          <MockedProvider mocks={[]}>
            <Countries />
          </MockedProvider>
        );
        pageTitle = component.getByText(mockPageTitle);
        loadingMessage = component.getByText(mockLoadingMessage);
      });
      done();
    });

    it('should have a title', () => {
      expect(pageTitle).not.toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('should have a loading status', () => {
      expect(loadingMessage).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
  });
```

Instead of trying to call component.getTextBy in each test, I moved them into the beforeAll, and assigned the output to variables. Each test uses the variables for their tests. I also wrote a test for my Routes component, and I was still able to call fireEvent.click() on the components.

I would be very interested in any feedback from anyone who has a more experience with testing-library on this. It seems better than what I had, but I want to make sure it's really the best approach.

Thanks.